# FORFILES not deleting files in subdirectory

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file

Below is my `forfiles` one-liner:

```
FORFILES /P "X:\LOGS\HS" /S /M *.log  /D -1 /C "CMD /C del /Q @FILE"qq ~q
```

Although I have the `/S` option to delete log files in `X:\LOGS\HS`, there are several subdirectories and it is not deleting log files further down the tree. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would put it down to spaces in the file/path name

when

```
FORFILES /P "X:\LOGS\HS" /S /M *.log  /D -1 /C "CMD /C del /Q @FILE"qq ~q
```

encounters X:\LOGS\HS\My Folder\Stuff.log, it will pass it to the `del` command as

> del X:\LOGS\HS\My Folder\Stuff.log

where del will then try to remove the files `X:\LOGS\HS\My` and `Folder\Stuff.log`

To overcome this, you have to give the system some quotes to wrap the file name in.

```
FORFILES /P "X:\LOGS\HS" /S /M *.log  /D -1 /C "CMD /C del /Q ""@FILE"""qq ~q
```

should give you a little more success